# Kubernetes - force pod restart if container fails to re-trigger init containers

Tags: kubernetes

I found in my pod that if a container fails or is killed due to failing liveness probe, the container is restarted, but the pod is not.

This means that `initContainers` are not run again in a case of a crashed container.

In my case, I do need to run one of the `initContainers` every time the main container fails.

Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you ever find a creative solution to this?  I'm running into a similar situation, where I use an initContainer to retrieve an oAuth token, but if the main container fails, k8s will keep retrying until the oAuth token is expired, at which point the main container is guaranteed to failed.  So would want to restart the entire pod.  But haven't been able to find a creative answer to this.

Comment: You have two options as I see it. (1) Use a sidecar container, but this means keeping a whole container up for this, and it's hard to discard the data. (2) Use the preStart hook to "do the magic", but will require a good piece of code to do it cleanly. Depending on your need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, this is simply not supported: `livenessProbe` is a ["container level" probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes) and if this probe fails only the said container is restarted, not the whole Pod

Though, you'll be glad to know that this behaviour is currently being implemented on this PR: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/pull/2342.

As a workaround before it's done and you eventually update, you'd have to rethink why you really need your `initContainers` in the first place, and consider a different co-ordination between your pod containers (be they initContainers or not) through a shared volume or some other scenarios depending on your use case.

Comment: If you need to run specific commands everytime container restarts. You can use postStart Command to handle that

Comment: I understand. I think I have a valid requirement. I want to create something temporary in my `initContainer` that is used and discarded by the main container. But has to be repeated if the main container fails (restarted). Doing this with a side car container seems impossible...